# XAMPP website can access the website other page but not on apache2

Tags: php, apache2

Using PHP 7.4.32 Ubuntu 22.04. I Got Website that has already tested on XAMPP  both on Linux and windows. There's the first page we open are asking the user to put the id and password on `localhost/` and it will be directed on `localhost/login`. Testing on Apache2 Webserve will result page 404 not found on `localhost/login`. So I tried to open where the page folder are on browser `localhost/app/views/partials/` where the result is showing 404 not found with the real website layout.
Couldn't find any error in logs

Here's my Config.php where it define the folder

```
//Application resource access status
define("AUTHORIZED", 200);
define("UNAUTHORIZED", 401);
define("NOROLE", 404);
define("FORBIDDEN", 403);

// Application Files and Directories 
define("IMG_DIR",  "assets/images/");
define("FONTS_DIR",  "assets/fonts/");
define("SITE_FAVICON", IMG_DIR . "favicon.jpg");
define("SITE_LOGO", IMG_DIR . "logo.jpg");

define("CSS_DIR", SITE_ADDR . "assets/css/");
define("JS_DIR", SITE_ADDR . "assets/js/");
define("APP_DIR", "app/");
define("SYSTEM_DIR", "system/");
define("HELPERS_DIR", "helpers/");
define("LIBS_DIR", "libs/");
define("LANGS_DIR", "languages/");
define("MODELS_DIR", APP_DIR . "models/");
define("CONTROLLERS_DIR", APP_DIR . "controllers/");
define("VIEWS_DIR", APP_DIR . "views/");
define("LAYOUTS_DIR", VIEWS_DIR . "layouts/");
define("PAGES_DIR", VIEWS_DIR . "partials/");
define("AUDIT_LOGS_DIR", "logs/");
```

here's my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
Options -Indexes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?request_uri=$1 [NC,L,QSA,B]
```

here's my website.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/website
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Why does the website give 404 not found when open `localhost/login`? It only works on Xampp windows and Xampp Linux not in the apache2 webserver.

Sorry if this is too long, I'm new on this.

Already tried to change  the .htaccess and permission but still the same

Comment: You're not making sense to me. You're telling me it works under XAMPP or LAMPP both on linux and windows. Both of those use Apache2. Then you're saying it's not working on Apache2. How are you running Apache2 where it doesn't work?

Comment: Ah sorry for that. What i mean is its working xampp but not on Apache2Webserver

Comment: What operating system is it not working on for Apache2, and is that operating system also running XAMPP/LAMPP?

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 and I already tried xampp for linux too. But it works just fine. i can open the localhost/login. When I tried with apache2 webserver its only giving me result 404 not found.

Comment: On Ubuntu, running Apache2 directly, you may be running into an AllowOverride issue where your entire .htaccess file is not being read. Another possibility is your rewrite engine may be disable. Try placing `AllowOverride All` into your website.conf file, then restart apache2: `sudo service apache2 reload`.  You might also need to enable the rewrite module: `sudo a2enmod rewrite` then `sudo service apache2 reload`

Comment: make it an answer. it works. Thankss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Ubuntu, running Apache2 directly, you may be running into an AllowOverride issue where your entire .htaccess file is not being read. Another possibility is your rewrite engine may be disabled. Try placing `AllowOverride All` into your website.conf file, then restart apache2: `sudo service apache2 reload`. You might also need to enable the rewrite module: `sudo a2enmod rewrite` then `sudo service apache2 reload`